# How do i deeplink to a specific page on my Android App

Tags: android, deep-linking

I'm trying to deeplink to a specific page on my Android app.

This is what i've tried:

```
DeepLinkingTest://?screen=ResetResponse
```

but it just opens the app home page

**Update:**

I've just tried:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <data android:scheme="deeplinkingtest"
                      android:host="resetresponse"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

but still opening on home page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add intent filter for the activity that you want to open via deep link to its definition in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. Here is an example:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_title_viewgizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
        <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="example"
              android:host="gizmos" />

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In this example, `GizmosActivity` is the activity you want to start via deep link.

Comment: I've just tried this but no luck, i've made edits explaining what happened

Comment: You're adding intent filter to your homepage (launcher activity). That's why deeplink opens that activity. Add your intent filter inside the definition of activity that you want to start.

Comment: i'm trying to get the scheme,host,pathPrefix part to work but it doesn't seem to be cooperating, the URL is this: https://callum.pixelpin.co.uk/SignIn/ResetRequest.aspx