# How to deeplink to specific page in cordova android app?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, deep-linking

I am using [launchmyapp](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme) plugin to create scheme url for my cordova android app. I have created myapp:// as my scheme and am using `intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=myapp://;S.browser_fallback_url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.myapp;end`
inside an `<a>`tag to open the app from web browser.

Now when I want to open any specific page (like settings page) of my app using the scheme URL.
I tried using `myapp://settings` as suggested on the plugin's page but it doesn't seem to work. Again the homepage of my app is only getting opened.

I have tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38826237/how-do-i-deeplink-to-a-specific-page-on-my-android-app), but it doesn't seem to work. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had achieved this using [cordova-universal-links-plugin](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin)

step 1 : install  [cordova-universal-links-plugin](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin)

step 2 : add below tag in your project's config file

```
<universal-links>
    <host name="yourappname.com" scheme="http">
        <path event="launchedAppFromLink" url="*" />
    </host>
</universal-links>
```

step 3 : Subscribe the above event "launchedAppFromLink" on device ready event. by adding below code

```
universalLinks.subscribe('launchedAppFromLink', 
onApplicationDidLaunchFromLink);

function onApplicationDidLaunchFromLink(eventData) {

  console.log('Did launch app from the link: ' + eventData.url);

}
```

after this your app link will be like : http://yourappname.com/

step 4 : on clicking above link if your app is installed in device then it will open.

step 5 : to open app specific register on [branch.io](https://branch.io/)

step 6 : register your app. After app registration it gives a link which is used to redirect or open the app.

step 7 : after that link just add your page name for example "myappname.app.link/yourapppage.html" and it will open that same page in mobile if your app is installed and if not then it will redirect to playstore with your app link